# How to transform a list of dictionaries, containing nested lists into a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, json-normalize

I have a list of dicts:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'a', 'counts': [{'dog': 2}]}, 
          {'name': 'b', 'counts': [{'cat': 1}, {'capibara': 5}, {'whale': 10}]}, 
          {'name': 'c', 'counts': [{'horse':1}, {'cat': 1}]]
```

I would like to transform this into a pandas dataframe like so:

| Name | Animal | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | dog | 2 |
| b | cat | 1 |
| b | capibara | 5 |
| b | whale | 10 |
| c | horse | 1 |
| c | cat | 1 |

In the current code, I try to normalize it:

```
from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(list_of_dicts, 'counts')
```

But I think I am going in the wrong direction. Also, if I do a simple `df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)` , it results in each list of dicts being a single row value, which is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `record_path` and `meta` parameters of `pandas.json_normalize` must be used.
- The columns will then be the animals, which are stacked into a single column.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'a', 'counts': [{'dog': 2}]}, {'name': 'b', 'counts': [{'cat': 1}, {'capibara': 5}, {'whale': 10}]}, {'name': 'c', 'counts': [{'horse':1}, {'cat': 1}]}]

# load and transform the dataframe
pd.json_normalize(list_of_dicts, 'counts', 'name').set_index('name').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Animal', 0: 'Frequency'})

# display(df)
  name    Animal  Frequency
0    a       dog        2.0
1    b       cat        1.0
2    b  capibara        5.0
3    b     whale       10.0
4    c     horse        1.0
5    c       cat        1.0
```

Comment: nice solution, i have to keep studying these nice pandas methods :)

Comment: @blah glad this worked for you. Yes, there are methods for transforming dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Try `json_normalize` with `melt`:

```
(pd.json_normalize(list_of_dicts, record_path='counts', meta='name')
   .melt('name', var_name='Animal', value_name='Frequency')
   .dropna()
)
```

Output:

```
   name    Animal  Frequency
0     a       dog        2.0
7     b       cat        1.0
11    c       cat        1.0
14    b  capibara        5.0
21    b     whale       10.0
28    c     horse        1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(list_of_dicts, 'counts').melt().dropna()
```

Comment: this won't have the `'name'` column

Comment: Ah, good shout :-) I forgot about it ... I see others have already answered it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [50]: df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts).explode('counts')
In [74]: df.counts = df.counts.apply(lambda x: list(x.items())[0])

In [77]: df[['Animal', 'Frequency']] = pd.DataFrame(df['counts'].tolist(), index=df.index)

In [79]: df.drop('counts', 1, inplace=True)

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
  name    Animal  Frequency
0    a       dog          2
1    b       cat          1
1    b  capibara          5
1    b     whale         10
2    c     horse          1
2    c       cat          1
```